# javascript sort json of locations by distance

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find the three closest locations and display the information on html (https://snag.gy/zSL4pO.jpg).

I was able to find the closest location, but with I can't get any further. In Java I would create a list of locations and would then sort them by distance. Whats the easiest way to get this done in javascript?

Current function:

```
function nearestLocation(position) {
    var myLocation;
    var currentLng = position.coords.longitude
    var currentLat = position.coords.latitude;
    var locationLng;
    var locationLat;
    var dx;
    var dy;
    var distance;
    var nearestAttraction = 15000; // ein extrem weit entfernter Ort (unrealistisch)

    var locationID = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        myLocation = locations[i];
        locationLng = myLocation[2];
        locationLat = myLocation[1];
        dx = 71.5 * (currentLng - locationLng);
        dy = 111.3 * (currentLat - locationLat);
        distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        if (distance < nearestAttraction) {
            nearestAttraction = distance;
            locationID = i;
        }
        console.log('Distance ' + i + ': ' + distance);
    }
    localStorage.setItem('currentLat', currentLat);
    localStorage.setItem('currentLng', currentLng);
    localStorage.setItem('locationID', locationID);
    showLocation(locationID, nearestAttraction);
}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: You have an array, so why not use the `sort()` function?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, using sort would be easy but there isn't a variable in the json which I can compare it to directly.  In my function I first need to calculate the distance and after I could sort it by that value.

Hope you understand where my problem is.

Comment: Just calculate the appropriate value inside the sort function. Could I ask what the significance is of multiplying `dx` and `dy` by 71.5 / 111.3?

Answer (score 0):

you can use sort() function.

first, make an array.
var elements=[];

second, fill array with json values

element.unshift({location:name,dist:distance});

or

element.unshift([name,distance]);//this would be faster

third, sort your array.

element.sort(function(a,b){return b.dist-a.dist;});//with object {}.

element.sort(function(a,b){return b[1]-a[1];});

fourth, use wherever you want.

element[0].place;//name of nearest place.(object)

element[0][0];//name of nearest place.(array)

-------end--------
if you have any question, ask me.

p.s. use Math.hypot(); instead of Math.sqrt();//Math.hypot is Faster but no for legacy browsers

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine was able to help me out. This is the code which works for me:

```
function nearestLocation(position) {

    var myLocation;
    var currentLng = position.coords.longitude
    var currentLat = position.coords.latitude;
    var locationLng;
    var locationLat;
    var dx;
    var dy;

    var distance;
    var nearestAttraction = 15000; // ein extrem weit entfernter Ort (unrealistisch)

    var locationID = 0;

    //Annahme: Maximal drei Attraktionen
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        var location = locations[i];
        locationLng = location[2];
        locationLat = location[1];
        dx = 71.5 * (currentLng - locationLng);
        dy = 111.3 * (currentLat - locationLat);
        distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

        location.push(distance);
        var output = "";
        output += distance.toString();
    }

    console.log(locations);

    locations.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a[8] - b[8];
    });

    console.log(locations);

    //Fuer Uebung 5c: Speichern der aktuellen Position und naechsten Attraktion im localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('currentLat', currentLat);
    localStorage.setItem('currentLng', currentLng);
    localStorage.setItem('locationID', locationID);
    showLocation();
}
```